# Stream Audio from Linux Server with Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, audio, streaming

I have a large catalog of audio on a Linux (CentOS 5) server that I would like to expose to an existing .NET web site.  Is there any way to stream the media from the Linux server through my web site using Silverlight?  If so, how would a person go about setting it up?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about adaptive streaming, this is really easy - just share the audio out over HTTP, then add a MediaElement (or something like http://smf.codeplex.com if you want it to be fancy, see my caveat at http://blog.paulbetts.org/index.php/2009/11/22/patching-silverlight-media-framework-to-work-with-mp4wmv-files/) and point it towards your Linux server running Lighttpd or Apache.

The critical bit though, is that Silverlight will only be allowed to access the hosting site by default, so you'll need to create a clientaccesspolicy.xml file ( http://www.silverlighthack.com/post/2008/11/08/Silverlight-clientaccesspolicyxml-files-for-the-Enterprise-(Part-1-of-2).aspx ) to allow SL access to your Linux server